# Assign macro to a cell corresponding to the row of automatically generated buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I've managed to create a form where the user can expand the fields of a pivot table and, once they've completely expanded a field/branch, a button will appear in column E and that pivot field data is concatenated in column J (there are some hidden columns).

What I want is for the user to click an auto-generating button in column E which exports the corresponding data in column J to a list, somewhere on the workbook.

My code below automatically generates the buttons for fully expanded fields, but I have no idea how to write the code to link each button to the corresponding cell in column J - this is probably not very difficult but any help would be appreciated.

[image: Pivot table]

```
Sub buttonGenerator()
Dim btn As Button
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
Dim t As Range
Dim size As Integer

size = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottable1").TableRange2.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To size Step 1
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 4))) Then
      Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 5))
      Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
      With btn
        .OnAction = "btnS"
        .Caption = "Add to summary" '& i
        .Name = "Btn" & i
        End With
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

Sub buttonAppCaller()
    MsgBox Application.Caller
End Sub
```

So here is my code .. it is throwing Runtime error 1004 "Unable to get the Buttons property of the worksheet class". Not sure what I've done wrong but I need to get the data from the cell next to the button to copy over to the bottom of a list in sheet 2 when that particular button is clicked. Please help!

```
Sub btnS()
    Dim dest As Range
    Dim origin As Range

    origin = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1) 'input data from cell next to button click
    dest = Worksheets("Form Output").Range("A1") 'output data to list in sheet 2 - "Form output"
    Set dest = origin
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `Integer` for row counts as you did for `size`. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.
2. The procedure every button invokes is called `btnS` as you defined in `.OnAction = "btnS"`. Therefore you need a `Sub` with that name **in a Module**.
3. You can use `Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell` to get the cell under a button and from that cell you can determine the row or column.

   ```
   Public Sub btnS() 'sub name must match `.OnAction` name
       MsgBox ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
   End Sub
   ```
4. Instead of using `ActiveSheet` I recommend to use a specific worksheet like `Worksheets("your-sheet-name")` if you plan to use it on a specific sheet only. `ActiveSheet` can easily change and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Can you walk me through step 3 as I'm still relatively new to VBA and programming in general. I need to get the corresponding data from next to the button to add to a list on sheet 2 when clicked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TopLeftCell` returns the cell under the button and with `TopLeftCell.Offset(row, column)` you can offset from there a specific amount of rows or columns eg `Offset(0, -2)` to move 2 columns left from there. Give it a try yourself and if you get stuck or errors show your code (in your original question) and ask something related to it.

Comment: So I've added my code above.. I'm getting a runtime error 1004. I', trying to get the data from next to a clicked button over to column A in sheet 2. Thanks.

Comment: @TWilken instead of `Set` use `dest.Value = origin.Value` to copy the value of the origin cell into the destination cell. These are VBA basics so I recommend you to read some VBA basic tutorial to understand how variables and objects are handled.

Comment: Hi sorry sorry I've fixed that though my fundamental issue seems to be the error "Unable to get the Buttons property of the Worksheet class".

Comment: I can't see what is wrong with this line of code `origin = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1)`

Comment: @TWilken You net to `Set origin` because `Offset` refers to a cell/range and that is an object and object need to use `Set` where values must not use `Set`. That's why I suggested to read a tutorial to understand how variables and objects are handled.